# How to get the number of servers your discord bot is on

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot website for a client, and he needs the real-time count on how many servers his discord bot is on, displayed in the website. I do not know about discord.js and couldn't find a simple answer.

These are the things I've done already:

- Added the discord.js from node.js
- Tried multiple solutions on StackOverflow(none gave me a correct answer)

```js
let element = document.getElementById('serverCount')
let serverCount;

// This is where the code to get the discord bot server count should be
// It should be stored on the serverCount

element.textContent = serverCount
```

```html
<h1 id="container">
        Trusted by <b id="serverCount"></b> servers!
    </h1>
```

- Watched lots of tutorials but all of them were about coding the discord bot but I unfortunately couldn't understand a thing

Comment: It is a bad idea to host your Discord Bot in the same process with the website. What you could be doing is make a Discord bot that updates a database, rabbitmq, etc with the current serverCount. All the web clients access the database, rabbitmq, ... to retrieve the current time. I would try something simpler and try to first understand databases, PubSub, Key-Value-Store, and so on. Look up how websites retrieve their data and how you can populate the data.

Comment: This question is far too open-ended, but to be general: the bot knows how many servers its in through the `client.guilds.cache.size` property. You just need to be able to retrieve that value on your page from the bot client. This can be done in plenty of ways, such as the ones Tin mentioned above. Personally I'd just run a minimal Node web through the bot that can serve the server count through a GET endpoint, but that's just one of many ways. There's not a whole lot you can do from your position if the bot itself doesn't expose the member count, the functionality needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of servers your bot is in by:

```js
await client.guilds.cache.fetch(); // update the chache for accurate info.
let serverCount = client.guilds.cache.size;
```